# How to insert into MySQL using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am just learning about databases and I want to be able to store user inputs. What would be a basic example on how to get form data and save it to a database using PHP?

Also making the form secure from [SQL attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Check out PDO: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html. +1 for wanting to learn to do it right. :)

Comment: Its also in the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### File *sample.html*

```
<form action="sample.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

#### File *sample.php*

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mysampledb');

    // replace every piece of data in SQL with question mark 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO SampleTable (name, text) VALUES (?,?)"
    //                                  2 question marks ^^^
    // prepare this query
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    // bind every variable, adding s for each to the types string
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['text']);
    //     2 s letters ^^        ^^   2 variables   ^^

    /* Execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This is a very basic example. Many PHP developers today are turning to [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). Mysqli isn’t obsolete, but PDO is *much* easier, IMHO.