# how to save data dynamically to database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

JQUERY CODE

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $(".left .inputs").append("<li><input type ='text' name='name[]' class='txtbox1'></li>");
        $(".right .inputs").append("<li><input type ='text' name='grade[]' class='txtbox'></li>");
    });
 });
```

MY PHP CODE

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die('cannot connect to database error: '.mysql_error());
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['grade']))
    {

        $desk_report = $_POST['name'];//contains array value
        $desk_action = $_POST['grade'];//contains array value
        foreach($desk_report as $key=>$user) { //Loop through arrays
            if (!empty($desk_report[$key]) && !empty($desk_action[$key])) {
                mysql_select_db("quickbook", $con);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO student_reg(relative_name,relative_grade) VALUES ('$desk_report[$key]','$desk_action[$key]')";
                if ($sql_run = mysql_query($sql)) {
                    echo 'ok.'; 
                } else {
                    echo '*Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to add inputs data to database.i created a code.but this is not working .can you help me?

Comment: please don't use mysql_* function check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: what output it showing?

Comment: @DiliniWasana May be because you forgot to call the php page using ajax.

Comment: @DiliniWasana is that white page or what ?

Comment: @DiliniWasana I could not see any submit or ajax call there, you should pass the values to the server in some way.

Comment: @DiliniWasana how are u calling this php code ?

Comment: @DiliniWasana, can you post the ajax request you are making? Also, check whether it is doing it by post

Answer (score 1):

Check the database which you used is exists or not,
try your code like

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die('cannot connect to database error: '.mysql_error());

    //add this line to your code here instead of in for loop
    mysql_select_db('quickbook',$con) or die("Could not select database!");
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['grade']))
    {
        $desk_report = $_POST['name'];//contains array value
        $desk_action = $_POST['grade'];//contains array value
        foreach($desk_report as $key=>$user) { //Loop through arrays
            if (!empty($desk_report[$key]) && !empty($desk_action[$key])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO student_reg(relative_name,relative_grade) VALUES ('$desk_report[$key]','$desk_action[$key]')";
                if ($sql_run = mysql_query($sql)) {
                    echo 'ok.'; 
                } else {
                    echo '*Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you searched it for, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747868/how-to-insert-into-mysql-using-prepared-statement-with-php