# Why do I get a 500 error? (MySQL php)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<head>
HTML CODE
<?
$username="xxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxx";
$database="xxxxxx";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

$escape = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('',$_POST["name"],$_POST["soort"])";
$escape2 = "DELETE monster FROM monster LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN( ID ) AS ID, NAME, PREF
            FROM monster
            GROUP BY NAME, PREF
            ) AS KeepRows ON monster.ID = KeepRows.ID
            WHERE KeepRows.ID IS NULL";

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($escape);
$query2=mysql_real_escape_string($escape2);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("MySQL error: Kan inte ansluta till databasen.");
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time i run this(from another file, containing the name and soort post's) I get an 500 internal server error. First I figured that the queries may be the problem, but they don't even get executed. However, i tried to escape the queries. But still error.
What is wrong with this code? (note: $escape2 is some code i found that removes duplicates in the database. But i don't really know how to format it so that it can be used through php.)

Comment: What do u actually want to do? Vague and confusing... please describe

Comment: what do your error logs say?

Comment: The latest log: [24-Oct-2013 07:15:44 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/monster.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

problem in insert into statement

it should be

```
$escape = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('',".$_POST['name'].",".$_POST['soort'].")";
```

it is preferable to write colums name while writing insert queries

if column contains string values like `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` then use quoted_printable_decode

pass `null` if column is autoincrement

[insert statment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

```
$escape = "INSERT INTO monster (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['name']."',".$_POST['soort'].")";
```

or

```
$escape = "INSERT INTO monster (col2, col3) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."',".$_POST['soort'].")";
```

Comment: I do not think that this is going to work. You haven't **quoted** the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('', '".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["soort"]."')";
```

**Please do not insert values without escaping.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('', '".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["soort"]."')";
```

---

Also I would suggest to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748127/1237747) because it is bad experience to *build* queries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have cool proposition for you. What do you say about some advanced PHP? One step further into great world of safe PHP + MySQL apps?

Introducting to you a [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). (I know this is not answer to your question but you can consider it). Example of use on your queries:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);

$insertQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO monster VALUES ("", :name, :soort)');
$deleteQuery = $db->prepare('DELETE monster FROM monster LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN( ID ) AS ID, NAME, PREF
FROM monster
GROUP BY NAME, PREF
) AS KeepRows ON monster.ID = KeepRows.ID
WHERE KeepRows.ID IS NULL');

//to execute query:
$deleteQuery->execute();
//or with params:
$insertQuery->execute(array(
  ':name'  => $_POST['name'],
  ':soort' => $_POST['soort'],
));
```

Cool, huh? There is more... Now according to your problem it could be everything (as we don't have error log) but my guess is:

- Try to use `<?php` instead of `<?`
- `$escape = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('',{$_POST["name"]},{$_POST["soort"]})";`

**EDIT:**
As you provided error log - now I'm sure that problem is in `$escape` query. It's because you used `$escape = "` <- and then `$_POST["name"]` so there was a collision of " (if I can say so).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Whenever you insert string type of values in the database using query it has to pass in the quote format. So you just need to change your insert query here.

$query = "INSERT INTO monster VALUES ('', '".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["soort"]."')";

write query like this.
```

-
Thanks